# Twoside option for exam class

Tags: exam, books

I wrote an entire book, 700 pages long, which contains 1000 math questions solved. When I started the book, however, I had no idea what each document class meant. I recently tried to put the book with the `twoside` option and it didn't work, searching in the forums I saw that this option doesn't exist for the `exam`. I tried to, but I can't create a resolution environment similar to the one provided by the `exam` class, with the `solution` box just below the question. I am sending an image as an example. I need help with: either finding a way to put the `exam` as `twoside`, or taking everything to the `book` and creating a resolution environment similar to the one provided by the `exam`. I tried some alternatives like the `exsol` package, and the `probsol`, but I found the documentation presented quite complex and did not understand what should be done... I know how to place the enumerations of the pages alternating in the `exam`, but the pages do not shift so that it is in print format.

[image]

Comment: I just looked at `exam.cls` in texlive it is based on `article` and passes all options to `article` so `twoside` should work in `exam` just as it does in `article` If an example isn't working as you expect post a small but complete example to your question so people can debug.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle `exam` sets one inch margins on all sides, so the OP's desire to have offsetting margins won't be visible.

Comment: @DonHosek ah.. well that's me: I look at the code, not the typeset result:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I looked at the documentation 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What the `twoside` option does is enable the alternating of even and odd side margins and also differing headers on even and odd pages. Since `exam` uses the same margins on all pages and the same headers on all pages, there is no visible effect from the `twoside` option but it *is* there.

but the default layout of the `exam` class won't take advantage of this. For page headers, the `fancyhdr` package is popular: https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/fancyhdr for changing page layout, `geometry` is commonly used: https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/geometry

Comment: Thanks, Don! I thought the option wasn't working.